# Implode an element array with double quote format and separated by comma

Tags: php, jquery

This is silly question, but I've tried on lot time and no success.

I have an array based my database record from query select ike this

```
User1User2User3
```

So, I use implode to make them separated.
In my case, I use this for auto completed on jquery focusout.
In html form input, it must be lloked like this :

```
<input name='userdata' data-source='["User1", "User2", "User3"]' />
```

This is the implode :

```
$data =implode(' ", ', $users);
echo $data;

the input, looked like this : User1" , User2"
```

For the help, it so appreciated.

Comment: `$data = '"' . implode('", "', $users) . '"';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 $data ='" '.implode(' ", ', $users).'"';
```

this is not a solution but it can be work form now.

you have to change you query which give result like User1, User2, User3 So from that you can do easily implode.